# Setting RAG colours in a cell based on the % value of the adjoining cells value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Lots of info out there on more complicated use cases but nothing that helps in my specific situation which seems pretty simple.

I have two columns, A & B.
In both columns there is a numerical value with no decimal places.
I want to set RAG cell colour based on what percentage of column A column B is calculated at.

```
Red <30%
Amber >50%
Green 80%>
```

I will have about 300 lines of each column to run this formula over so hoping for something that I only need to define once.

Just struggling with the formula to apply here, I've fiddled around with wildcards etc but Google isn't playing ball.

Thanks for any advice, I'm sure the answer is simple as it doesn't seem like a difficult problem.

Tried setting colour ranges but the options for a non custom formula seem limited.
Tried using $ on columns in a formula but can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Comment: How you are calculation the percentage? Suppose you have 50 in A1 cell and 85 in B1 cell then what will be percentage?

Comment: Please share more info

Comment: So one column is a number of requirements, which is variable. One line it could be only 1 requirement, on others it could be 10. The second column is the number of requirements which is satisfied (compliant).

So requirements could be 10, compliance could be 2. Since this is under 30% compliance the cell would be coloured Red. If the number was 6 it would be greater than 50% and be amber.... and so on. The compliance number will never be greater than the requirements number.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, you can try the following 3 formulas under `Conditional formatting` --> `custom formula is`

1. `=AND(B111<A111*30%,B111<>"")` for Red
2. `=AND(B111>A111*80%,B111<>"")` for Green
3. `=AND(B111>A111*50%,B111<>"")` for Amber

*(**Do** adjust the formulas according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Thanks @marikamitsos those parameters worked an absolute treat.